# QML: Some keys are not handled after multiple key press / release

Tags: c++, qt, keyboard, qml

I have a strange problem only with special combinations of multiple keys. Here is a simple QML program:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    title: qsTr("untitled")
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true

    Item {
        focus: true

        Keys.onPressed: {
            console.log(event.key);
        }
    }
}
```

When I hold the following keys (in this order) "UP" + "LEFT" + "ESCAPE", this is displaying:

```
qml: 16777235
qml: 16777234
qml: 16777216
qml: 16777216
qml: 16777216
...
```

That is correct. But when I hold "Z" + "D" + "ESCAPE":

```
qml: 90
qml: 68
qml: 68
qml: 68
qml: 68
...
```

Here, the escape key is totally ignored ... This is not the only case where keys are ignored. I truly need to handle any key pressed by the user.

I have exactly the same issue with Qt with C++, any idea why?

Comment: Does it work in other applications? Maybe it is a hardware limitation.

Comment: Maybe, I tried here on Linux, I'll give a try on Windows.

Comment: using keyReleased instead of keyPressed

Comment: It shows 16777216 for me.

Comment: I tried on Windows and had the same result. Velkan, it worked for you? Did you try other multiple keys combinaison? (maybe W + D +  ESCAPE)

Comment: I didn't try others. Keyboards can have such hardware limitations.

Comment: For me it also does not work on Windows. However, works on macOS. Qt 5.9.8

Answer (score 0):

I think that it has to do with the special handling of the up and down key within Qt. If you hold the up and down key you will see that Qt is emiting an onReleased event although it is further pressed. I was unable to find an explanation of that. But I had a look to the driver level of the input and there everything was correct. Maybe this is a special feature so that scrolling through lists is easier, although for sure autorepeat should work as well for that.

The thing with the escape key could be a following issue, when already two keys are pressed that the third one won't appear. Since the up key is released in the first example (up gets released while pressed), effectivle only two keys are pressed in parallel.